# using numpy.any to match color in opencv gives strange results

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to turn on and off a relay based on the detection of a color in a frame from a webcam. Since it needs to do this in real time I chose to use numpy slicing. The problem is numpy ALWAYS detects the color I input unless I completely cover the camera and I'm just not seeing why.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import video

while True:
            ret,frame = cam.read()          
            img = frame.copy()
            sens = 20
            b = 0
            #roughly neon green
            img1B = 20
            img1G = 230
            img1R = 50  
            if np.any(np.logical_and(img[:,:,0]>=img1B-sens, img[:,:,0]<=img1B+sens)):
                b = True
            else:
                b = False
            if np.any(np.logical_and(img[:,:,1]>=img1G-sens, img[:,:,1]<=img1G+sens)):
                g = True
            else:
                g = False
            if np.any(np.logical_and(img[:,:,2]>=img1R-sens, img[:,:,2]<=img1R+sens)):
                r = True
            else:
                r = False                       
            print b,g,r
```

B,G,R shouldn't always be true unless the cam is seeing a neon green pixel so I'm not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Don't need  to over-complicate the problem by using `numpy` operations **thrice**. You may simply use [`cv2.inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) and [`cv2.countNonZero()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) to get your job done. The above steps can be modulated to a method which you may call from your `while` loop to process each webcam frame.

```
import cv2

def detect_color_blob(img_BGR, blob_color_BGR, tolerance, threshold):
    blob_color_lower = [blob_color_BGR[0] - tolerance, blob_color_BGR[1] - tolerance, blob_color_BGR[2] - tolerance]
    blob_color_upper = [blob_color_BGR[0] + tolerance, blob_color_BGR[1] + tolerance, blob_color_BGR[2] + tolerance]

    # Get a Binary Mask, where 255 => blob color found and 0=> blob color NOT found
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_BGR, blob_color_lower, blob_color_upper)

    # Check if the detected number of pixels is greater than threshold.
    return cv2.countNonZero(mask) > threshold
```